# I want to write a Shell program for my Laptop battery

Tags: bash, battery

I found many commands that fetch the battery status and Percentage like `upower -e` and so on. Now, I want to write a shell program for an alert message for "Battery Fully Charged" (As we get during Connected and Disconnected to internet) on the right corner with aero/transparency effect on mouse hover. Is it possible? Can such code be written?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the program that handles the desktop notifications... I'm not sure if it's the same on every desktop, but on XFCE it's `notify-send - a program to send desktop notifications` from the package `libnotify-bin`. It's a dependency of xubuntu-desktop, ubuntu-gnome-desktop, ubuntu-desktop, mythtv-frontend, so it sounds fairly universal.

It's handy for anything like new mail notifications, sensor changes (temp, fan, voltage), monitor log files for "segfault" or interesting hardware changes, weather alerts... sky's the limit. Anything a bash shell script (or process) can do, this can help.

Does that command/program work for you?

---

**OR/AND** there's also other programs for displaying dialogs from shell scripts, and giving info back to the shell script too. Probably overkill for your info-only purpose, and may use basic boxy windows, not the nice desktop notifications timed windows.

My XFCE (Linux Mint) comes with **`zenity`**`- Display graphical dialog boxes from shell scripts` already installed. It lets you ask questions and pass the answers back to your script, as in yes, no, cancel (1,2,3), even a few text characters... There's also:

- `yad - Yet Another Dialog - dialogs for shell` "a fork of Zenity with many improvements"
- `ssft - Shell Scripts Frontend Tool` but it may not have been updated since 2009

---

FYI, you could add a quick sound using `play` from the `sox` package ("Swiss army knife of sound processing"), best command line tool I've found to just play a sound file quickly. `vlc` plays sounds too, but is big & complicated & didn't sound as good (clicks, delayed a second, noticeable for a quick "bell" sound)

Comment: Well guided mate. Can you pass me on some helpful links? Since, I'm new to shell programming, I'd like to refer some codes.

Comment: None in particular stand out... LOTS of bash "guides" with hundreds of dry pages, but just searching for answers to problems as they come up works ok. Often on stackoverflow.com actually, or the unix & linux site, or here

Comment: Okay, I'll search for it. Actually my aim is to get notification as of aero effect when battery gets charged fully. Let's see if I can mak it.

Comment: I'd start with the built-in / default settings and see if they have that feature, or a setting to do something on an event like that... less work. Just found a not-bad bash scripting FAQ http://splike.com/wiki/Bash_Scripting_FAQ  And, if my answer worked out you can select/check-mark it too

Comment: `notify-send` worked like a charm. Over the years, I learnt a lot but so less about shell programming. This situation arrived again in my 2nd Laptop and happened to revisit this thread, and I could program my solution. I'm marking this answer Accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu already places battery percentage (and optionally time) in on the tray when running on battery, and produces a popup exactly like you described on battery critical.

Under what other circumstances would you want this popup?

Comment: But not when the Battery is Fully charged. So, if it can do that I would save my Laptop battery from over-charging.